# Android-Intent do not direct me well

Tags: android, android-intent

I simply want to pass another class when button is clicked,however I couldn't be succesfull so far.Here java code for intent:

```
mButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Internet.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

And here my androidmanifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Internet"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_internet"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>`
```

So what can be my mistake?Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it should be `Intent(FROM_ACTIVITY.this,TO_ACTIVITY.class);`

Comment: It already is.Isn't it?

Comment: no they both are same

Comment: I put wrong one.Let me fix it

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: So,please check it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106797/discussion-between-mohit-and-ali-yilmaz).

Comment: No,I'm not getting any error.This is not directing me the page that I want to go.

Comment: You should have some error message in LogCat. all else seems fine, please copy the logcat after clicking the button.

Comment: Get rid of the parentActivity and meta-data for now and try that.

Comment: It is fixed now,Thanks for all of your comments.